# Use of dot notation in web service WSDL causes sudzc compile errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sudzc

I'm hoping there is an easy fix for this, though I couldn't find anything. I am working with a WSDL file that contains some items using dot notation:

```
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Status" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Status.Code" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Status.Description" type="xs:string" />
```

When I generate the code using sudzc the output header file contains the dot notation:

```
      NSString* _Status;
      NSString* _Status.Code;
      NSString* _Status.Description;
```

Which of course does not compile in Objective C. This being generated code, I'm hoping there is an easy/automated way to correct this (rather than manually update using underscores or something). Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Damien

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and my answer is very inefficient one. I brute forced and changed the **classes name or in your case variable names** one by one and their references inside the codes. I tried lots of googling with no luck.

Hope if someone have way around for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Would it make sense to download and update the WSDL to replace the "." with, say "_" and then generate the code again? I know it would no longer be canonical, but this is a mature production web service that is unlikely to change. Thoughts?

Comment: Well thats a good option, just make sure you document in System overview document with very big or highlighted words ;) lol

Comment: It's actually not too bad. I updated the sudzc code, replacing ___ with . anywhere it appears within quotes - primarily within serialize: methods. Seems to be working. Once I am getting return values I'll be able to say definitely (can't proceed until I get valid credentials).

Comment: Nice work around, However while in my case I had this gigantic WSDL to deal with lol...but I will surely try this in future projects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find any easy way to fix this. XML schemas that include elements with "." in the name are known to be problematic with auto-generated code and languages that try to more easily navigate XML structures.

I've gotten into heated debates about this with data architects at my company who insist on using dot notation in their XML names, despite the fact that it makes it harder for developers to write XML manipulation code and harder for code generators to generate valid stub code.

If you have any ability to influence the schema used in your services, do everything possible to have the dots removed from element names. If you can't get that changed, you will probably be stuck with manually modifying all the generated code.

Comment: It's a mature production web service so there won't be any changes to it (not for my benefit at least!). Thanks for letting me know what I'm up against. Perhaps this is a good time to solve this problem generically...but let's see if anyone already has first :-)

Comment: If you're looking for a generic approach to handling this, you might consider putting an XSLT transformation between the XML you receive and your app, and then reverse the process when sending XML from your app to the service. It would be pretty straightforward XSLT if you wanted to do something like changing all dots to underscores on the way in and all underscores to dots on the way out. XSLT is not supported directly in Objective-C, but it can be done in C code and also by some third-party libraries.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I will keep that in mind. For now I've used underscores in code and dot anywhere they appear inside quotes. Hopefully it stays simple - I should know in another week. Thanks again.